# How can I elegantly make UITextField in UITableViewCell firstResponder?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a `UITableView` with several rows, which might contain `UITextField`s. I created a custom class for this `UITableViewCell`s. This custom class has a delegate, like this:

```
@interface GKCustomCell : UITableViewCell <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *textField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<UITextFieldDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

My `TableViewController` conforms to `<UITextFieldDelegate>` protocol, so I can assign myself in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    GKCustomCell *cell = (GKCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell.delegate = self;
    ...
    return cell;
}
```

The cell's methods directly call it's delegate's corresponding methods like this:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self.delegate textFieldDidEndEditing:textField];
}
```

So I already know how to access correctly `UITextField` events happened in my cells in my controller.

My problem is, that I want to select text fields (make them `firstResponder`) by some logic (for example, the next one on pressing Done in one). For this, I obviously need a reference for the `UITextField` in the cell, which don't and can't have (because rows are dequed dynamically, so I can't put a strong reference in my table view controller into a cell's inner object).

How can I elegantly access one of these `UITextField`s?

Answer (score 0):

Use custom blocks. Define a block in your cell.h like following -

```
typedef void (^textField_block_t)(UITextField * txtField);
```

Then create an instance of same as follows -

```
@property (copy) textField_block_t txtFieldBlock;
```

In cell.m, at whatever events you want to pass your text field to your TableViewController class, call the block like following -

```
if ([self txtFieldBlock])
{
    [self txtFieldBlock]([self textField]);
}
```

In your TableviewController's cellForRowAtIndexPath, you need to set this block like -

```
GKCustomCell *cell = (GKCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
 [cell setTxtFieldBlock:^(UITextField * txtField){
   //Here you will be getting your instance of textfield which belongs to that particular cell. Do whatever you want to do with it.

  }];
```

Comment: That's not answer for my question. I want reference for the UITextFields.

Comment: You got it, txtField is the reference for UITextField belonging to a particular cell.

Comment: Ok, you are right, but you misunderstood me. I still can't access the reference anytime I want (it will be available just after the cellForRow... is called). I don't see any advance of this over the much more simple `self.textFieldReference = cell.textField`...

Answer (score 0):

you can first set `textField.userInteractionEnabled = No` in storyborad or code so you can get events on tableView. 
 then in

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell  = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell.textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

now you can call textfield delegate methods 
Happy coding

Comment: That works only if you want to access the text field in the cell which you tapped. If you want to access a text field in an another cell (which might be offscreen, hence not even in memory), this method does not work. For example: I want to jump into the next field - how can I do that?

Comment: you still have indexpath, you can make the textfield in next cell first responder

Comment: How? Shall I explicitly call `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to get the cell? Is it "legal"?

Comment: I think  `NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];` and then you can get the new cell as `UITableViewCell *cell =[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section]]];`

Comment: Imagine the following: I have 10 text fields in the table, in 10 cells. Some of them are off-screen. If I press Done in the first one, I want to jump into the 10th. How can I do this?